# What is the difference between rude and abusive?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

If you flag a post, you will see a choice called "rude or abusive", what is difference between "rude" and "abusive"? They seem the same.

Comment: Why worry over what they "seem" to be? Check them up in a good dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being "rude" is more of a passive action. If you walk by someone without greeting him or her, that would be rude.

Being "abusive" is being active in causing offense. If you scold, push or bump into someone (intentionally), or otherwise use "force," that would be being abusive.

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: A 'rude' posting could be one that uses crude or offensive language, but without personally insulting the person it's addressed to.

Comment: I don't think being offensive is similar to being abusive. It seems that abuse seems to entail certain power imbalance.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of flagging a post several actions, or reactions, tend to be grouped together. In this example "rude or abusive". In this view "rude" can be an action that induces a reaction whereas "abusive" is a direct action with intent (or uses inappropriate words or statements).

Examples:

rude: "your post is dumb"

abusive: "no one with a brain would post something so dumb".

Answer (score 0):

Rude is general and vague, not directed at one person speciffically .
Abusive is targeted and direct to a person .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

"Rude" implies a one-time offense against etiquette. "Abusive" connotes a pattern of offensive behavior over time.

Moreover, it's quite possible for partners in a relationship of any sort to be abusive to one another without being overtly rude. Abusive behavior can often occur covertly and by stealth; rude behavior cannot.

Comment: This is a common use of "abusive", but it doesn't explain what an "abusive post" might be, per the question.

Comment: The title of the post was "What is the difference between rude and abusive?" The OP then repeated it by asking "What is difference between 'rude' and 'abusive'? They seem the same." An example was given relating to "rude or abusive posts" but it was obvious that he or she was looking for a general insight into the meanings of those words that went beyond that. My response fully answered the question, whether the issue was "posts," "relationships," "people," etc. You're nitpicking.